# How to transfer data between a replacement SSD and old SSD?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, backup, clone

My plan is to *replace* my laptop's current 256GB SSD with a 1 or 2 TB SSD. This means that the new SSD will be completely empty without any OS, or my data... I am using Windows 10 on the subject computer.

I have the ability to create a "Windows backup Image" (I do this weekly anyway) of my old SSD and put it on one of my external drives and I was hoping to "restore" this backup image onto the new SSD after it is installed into the laptop, so I can resume exactly how I'd left off but with more space. However, does Windows need to already be on that new SSD in order to do this? If so, **are there any other solutions which solve the problem of needing to transfer data/OS image from current SSD to new SSD?**

**Please Note:** This is not a request for a software recommendation. I am wondering about the *method* for which to go about this. For example, is it possible to restore an image to the SSD after the drive has been installed when the computer now has no current OS installed on it? Without an OS, how is this achieved?

Comment: @ccpizza ok thanks. Well, I'm less wondering about the actual software and more the method. How can I physically get a windows image onto the SSD when the subject computer has no current OS on it (in its state from after the new SSD install)?

Comment: Methods, you have the option of removing the drive and copying one to the other sector for sector with hardware.  Or use a USB to Sata adapter to the new disk on the laptop. Start with sector by sector. Once completed and working, resize/move partitions as necessary and "grow" the filesystems to fill.  So... USB  *or* SATA cables (desktop) *or* a duplication dock.

Comment: The suggested duplicate is a software question, it is not an exact duplicate. This is a configuration question, more importantly a *process* question. It is not answered at all by the existing question.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to go about this, and this could largely be interpreted as a request for a software recommendation or opinion, so don't be surprised if this question is closed eventually... Personally I don't feel Windows does this itself very well at all and I recommend NOT attempting it his way.

That said [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) is excellent at performing this type of operation. I have used it on several occasions, both moving to larger and smaller disks and it has worked perfectly every time.

I would highly recommend it, also Macrium has several tutorials on their site about moving partitions or whole disks from one physical device to another. Check out the [Macrium Reflect 6 Knowledgebase](http://knowledgebase.macrium.com/display/KNOW/Macrium+Reflect+KnowledgeBase) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with Linux I'd suggest using a bootable USB stick with [clonezilla](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/pm-express/) which is free, otherwise you could use a free/trial version of a Windows based application like [Macrium](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) or [DriveImageXML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm) etc.